# Nested one to many relationship jpa spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have three classes - Document, Page, Sentence. A Document will have multiple Pages & each Page will have multiple Sentences. I'm trying to map One to Many relationship using Spring Data JPA annotation. But it only works when there are only one layer like - Document>Page. Doesn't work while it's Document>Page>Sentence.

Can anyone please give me a solution for how to do it for nested one to many relationship ?

My classes are given below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FILEID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idFile;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    private byte[] content;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "ID_MAIL_USER")
    private String idMailUser;

    @Column(name = "NUM_PAGES")
    private int numPages;

    @Column(name = "TO_ANALIZE")
    private boolean toAnalize;

    @Column(name = "HASH")
    private String hash;

    @Column(name = "EXTENSION")
    private String extension;

    @Column(name = "SIZE")
    private double size;

    @Column(name = "LINK_TO_DRIVE_FILE")
    private String linkToDriveFile;

    @Column(name="PATH")
    private String path;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Column(name = "PAGES")
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();

   // Setter Getters
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE")
public class Page implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PAGE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idPage;

    @Column(name = "PAGE_NUMBER")
    private int pageNum;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    private String content;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "SENTENCES")
    private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();

    // Setter Getters

}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SENTENCE")
public class Sentence implements Serializable {

    //private long idFile;

    //private long idPage;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SENTENCE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "PAGE_NUMBER")
    private int pageNumber;

    @Column(name = "ORDER")
    private int ord;

    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "HASH")
    private String hash;

   // Setter Getters

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: It works when I comment out the senteces field in Page class -  private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();  But when I try to keep sentences and give it one to many or many to many annotation - it doesn't work.

Comment: What is happening that you don't expect, or not happening that you expect?  Are you getting an error?   Also, your question says "One To Many" but you have `Page.sentences` annotated as `@ManyToMany`

Comment: I'm getting exceptions - org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'docRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1fd6708' of type .....

Comment: The error messages are explaining what's wrong.  You'll need to include the full stack in your question.  Help us help you, man.

Comment: I've tried both one to many and many to many actually. Here is the exceptions I'm getting https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SLkTsjLZ_Z4L2PbzXw6HVsB2K1GJcDZj . I should've mentioned. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OneToMany` mappings are incorrect. Correct it as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements Serializable {
    ......

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID")  //Name the foreign key column in PAGE table to DOCUMENT_ID
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();    
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE")
public class Page implements Serializable {
    ....

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PAGE_ID") //Name the forein key column in PAGE table to PAGE_ID
    private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Use `@JoinColumn` annotation instead of `@Column` to give the name of the foreign key that do the physical mapping between tables in your database.

Comment: I tried this. But this gave me those exceptions - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dj1UWbzPn_DPwgLisEs0FgCZZuqiGtET

Comment: Problem is in your database schema. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER integer, PAGE_NUMBER integer, PAGE_ID bigint, primary key (SENTENCE_ID))'`. Publish your sql file, if you need further help.

Comment: The tables are getting auto generated when I run the app for the first time. I'm not manually doing anything on DB. Should not be anything wrong with that. It's nested "one to many" relationship that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="document")
    @Column(name = "PAGES")
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PAGE")
public class Page implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_ID")
    private Document document;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="pages")
    @Column(name = "SENTENCES")
    private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SENTENCE")
public class Sentence implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="sentences")
    private List<Page> pages;

  
}
```

Here a `Document` One to Many relationship with `Pages`.
So.. we need define `mappedBy` in the entity we want to map another entity.. so in this case

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="document",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

and in referenced entity i.e. `Pages` we want foreign key `DOCUMENT_ID`, so we have to define it using

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk why everyone missed this (even the accepted answer), the error message states:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER integer, PAGE_NUMBER integer, PAGE_ID bigint, primary key (SENTENCE_ID))'
```

And he has a field inside `Sentence` called `ord` that he literally named `ORDER` like the SQL keyword so of course it will break.
The solution is just to rename that to anything else, but; if push comes to shove and god forbid you *REALLY* want to name it that way then surround it with backticks ` as such:

```java
@Column(name = "`ORDER`")
```

That will escape the keyword and allow you to use it as name.
Not sure if it's an H2-specific feature though, but either way renaming is the best way to go.